# Jquery does not display the value returned by the webMethod in the textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asynchronous, webmethod

I am trying to display the value returned by a webmethod using jquery but it does not work. The web method works fine and returns the value that I can even alert and see that value. But when trying to display that value in a textbox on the same page it does not work. I've checked lot of online solutions but in vain. Please help.

The commented code portions are just different approaches that I have been trying to display the value to the textbox but in vain.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function loadData(id) {
            PageMethods.loadDataToModal(id, onSucess, onError);

            function onSucess(result) {

                alert(result.firstname);
                //$('#firstname').input.setAttribute('value', result.firstname);
                //document.getElementById("txtfirstname").innerText = result.firstname;
                //$('#firstname').val( result.d.firstname);
                document.getElementById("txtLastname").innerText = result.lastname;
            }

            function onError(result) {
                alert('Something wrong.');
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method to set the content of a text box:

```
$('#txtLastName').val(result.lastname);
```

For example:

```js
$('#txtLastName').val("testing!!");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtLastName">
```

Comment: I have tried that and I also have ajax CDN included for bootstrap. But still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#firstname').val( result.d.firstname);
```

is probably the most straightforward way and the way you want to do it.

What you need to do is confirm that $('#firstname') returns the DOM object you are expecting. (IE: Does your input have id="firstname" and you don't have anything else with the same ID on the page.)

Are you sure that result.d.firstname has the data you need? You are alerting on result.firstname.

`.val()` is the correct jQuery method for setting an input's value.

Comment: My input has id="firstname" and I don't have anything else with same ID. I am alerting using $('#firstname').val( result.firstname); and I can see the data.   result.d.firstname doesn't show a value.

Comment: So, have you tried using it with result.firstname? You can test this in your browsers developer tools console window by entering `$('#firstname').val('teting')` and the input should change to testing.

Comment: I have tried the console window but the input didn't change to testing. it's still empty

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, it's impossible to say why it's not working. The fact that nothing changed when you typed it into the console means that your selector didn't match the DOM element. Here's a working js fiddle that updates the textbox when you click a button. http://jsfiddle.net/tf3bo8g5/

Comment: A trick I sometimes use to see if the selector is correct right is to enter either just `$('#firstname')` in the console (Firefox/firebug/chrome give better info about what it returns than IE developer tools) or try `$('#firstname').length` to see if you get the expected result of 1.